# Is it possible to write return statement in if block using java?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I want to return Vector according to if block but the code gives me the following error: `Add return statement`.

Is it possible to write return statement in if block?

```
public static  int[] zeroVectorBinning1( ImageFloat32 angle,ImageFloat32 Magnitude )
{
    for (int NumberOFChanks=0;NumberOFChanks<locations_original.size();NumberOFChanks++)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<angle.getHeight();i++)
                for(int j=0;j<angle.getWidth();j++)
            {
                int  orientaionVal=(int) angle.get(j, i);

                 if(orientaionVal<=0)
                    {int magnitudeVal=(int) Magnitude.get(j, i);
                    int[] Vector = new int[19];
                    Vector=zeroVector(19);
                    Vector[0]=magnitudeVal;
                    return Vector;
                    }
                else if(orientaionVal<=20)
                    {int magnitudeVal=(int) Magnitude.get(j, i);
                    int[] Vector = new int[19];
                    Vector=zeroVector(19);
                    Vector[1]=magnitudeVal;
                    return Vector;
                    }
                else(orientaionVal >= 0 && orientaionVal <=20)

                    {
                    int magnitudeVal=(int) Magnitude.get(j, i);
                    int[] Vector = new int[19];
                    Vector=zeroVector(19);
                    Vector[0]=magnitudeVal;
                    Vector[1]=magnitudeVal;
                    return Vector;

                    }

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Yes. Also give some other name than Vector for the variable

Comment: It is possible, but you haven't covered all the possible cases to which the program flow may go.

Comment: Rename Vector to something else. Vector is a keyword in java

Comment: @MukulGoel: It is not a keyword in Java.

Comment: remove the paranthesized statement after the else, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in having return statements in `if` blocks, but your method must have a return statement in any execution path.

Your for loops may never be executed (if, for example, `locations_original.size()` is 0), in which case none of the if blocks that contain the return statements will be reached. Therefore you must add a return statement following the loops.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

But your function still not return anything in the end, so you have to return something, even `null`.

So when you call this function, it should ne looking like this:

```
int[] fuctionResult = zeroVectorBinning1(....);
if (fuctionResult != null){
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could resolve this in two ways:

- At the end either throw an exception just before completing the method.
- Or at the end just return null.

Reason why compiler is complaining because, if `locations_original.size()` returns 0 then this method would never return anything which contradicts with what you said in your method that it will return an int array.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. But you need a return statement for every cases. Also if your for loop is never executed.

so add `return null`; at the end of your method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `if/else-if/else` parse is not complete, what does `else` with a condition like:

```
else(orientaionVal >= 0 && orientaionVal <=20)
```

mean? It's odd. Just omit the condition `(orientaionVal >= 0 && orientaionVal <=20)` of the last `else` sentence (and it's not  logically correct when `orientaionVal` is `0` or `20`),  or there will be no default else in the scope.

When return in the scope of a `if` sentence, we must make sure that under any condition there is a return, so:

- Make a default return out of the if-else scope
- Or be sure that the condition judgement is complete and there is a return under any condition.

So

Correct:

```
if(condition){
   return;
}
return;
```

Correct:

```
if(condition){
   return;
}else if(anotherCondition){
   return;
}else{
   return;
}
```

Wrong:

```
if(condition){
 return;
}
// no return ...
```

Wrong:

```
if(condition){
 return;
}else if(anotherCodition){
 return;
}
// no return ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Follow the code snippet for explanation.

```
public class TestSample {

    public static void main(String... w){
    int h = new TestSample().call();
        System.out.println(h);

    }

    public int call(){
        int j =0;
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(i==5){
                return i;
            }
        }

        return j;
    }

}
```

This prints 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getValue(){
 final int value = 3;
 if(value==1){
  return 1;
 }
 else if(value==2){
  return 2;
 }
 else if(value==3){
  return 3;
 }
 else{
  return -1;
 }
// no return because "else" covers all cases
}
```

In this case you have an "else" at the end, so every case is covered. but if you leave the else ...

```
public int getValue(){
 final int value = 3;
 if(value==1){
  return 1;
 }
 else if(value==2){
  return 2;
 }
 else if(value==3){
  return 3;
 }
return -1;
// ... you have to return something at the end of the method, because value could be >3 or < 1 and the code under the last else if will be executed
}
```